# "Resolution Failed! You application will not run, see the log for details"

Tags: c, firebase, unity-game-engine, firebase-authentication, firebase-analytics

I'm trying to run Force Resolve with Firebase, but it fails and doesn't work.

[image: Resolution Failed!]

JAVA_HOME of Windows is also set to the latest JDK, and the JDK in Unity uses the one prepared by Unity (JDK Installed with Unity is true).

I don't know what other information is needed. What should I do?

---

```
Gradle failed to fetch dependencies.
Failed to run 'C:\UnityProjects\UnityProjectName\Temp\PlayServicesResolverGradle\gradlew.bat --no-daemon -b "C:\UnityProjects\UnityProjectName\Temp\PlayServicesResolverGradle\PlayServicesResolver.scripts.download_artifacts.gradle" "-PANDROID_HOME=C:/Program Files/Unity/Editor/2019.2.6f1/Editor/Data/PlaybackEngines/AndroidPlayer\SDK" "-PTARGET_DIR=C:\UnityProjects\UnityProjectName\Assets\Plugins\Android" "-PMAVEN_REPOS=file:///C:/UnityProjects/Craft%20Offensive/Assets/Firebase/m2repository" "-PPACKAGES_TO_COPY=com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:17.2.0;com.google.firebase:firebase-iid:[20.0.0];com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-unity:6.6.0;com.google.firebase:firebase-common:19.1.0;com.google.firebase:firebase-app-unity:6.6.0;com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:19.0.0;com.google.firebase:firebase-auth-unity:6.6.0;com.google.firebase:firebase-database:19.1.0;com.google.firebase:firebase-database-unity:6.6.0;com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:20.0.0;com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging-unity:6.6.0" "-PUSE_JETIFIER=1" "-PDATA_BINDING_VERSION=3.4.0"'
stdout:
ERROR: JAVA_HOME is set to an invalid directory: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_161
Please set the JAVA_HOME variable in your environment to match the
location of your Java installation.
stderr:
exit code: 1
UnityEngine.Debug:LogError(Object)
Google.Logger:Log(String, LogLevel) (at Z:/tmp/tmp.cfOHeQ7pJN/third_party/unity/unity_jar_resolver/source/VersionHandlerImpl/src/Logger.cs:103)
GooglePlayServices.PlayServicesResolver:Log(String, LogLevel) (at Z:/tmp/tmp.CbcF1w0aJu/third_party/unity/unity_jar_resolver/source/PlayServicesResolver/src/PlayServicesResolver.cs:957)
GooglePlayServices.<GradleResolution>c__AnonStorey1:<>m__2(Result) (at Z:/tmp/tmp.CbcF1w0aJu/third_party/unity/unity_jar_resolver/source/PlayServicesResolver/src/GradleResolver.cs:369)
GooglePlayServices.<GradleResolution>c__AnonStorey2:<>m__0() (at Z:/tmp/tmp.CbcF1w0aJu/third_party/unity/unity_jar_resolver/source/PlayServicesResolver/src/GradleResolver.cs:468)
Google.RunOnMainThread:ExecuteNext() (at Z:/tmp/tmp.cfOHeQ7pJN/third_party/unity/unity_jar_resolver/source/VersionHandlerImpl/src/RunOnMainThread.cs:377)
Google.RunOnMainThread:<ExecuteAll>m__1() (at Z:/tmp/tmp.cfOHeQ7pJN/third_party/unity/unity_jar_resolver/source/VersionHandlerImpl/src/RunOnMainThread.cs:408)
Google.RunOnMainThread:RunAction(Action) (at Z:/tmp/tmp.cfOHeQ7pJN/third_party/unity/unity_jar_resolver/source/VersionHandlerImpl/src/RunOnMainThread.cs:234)
Google.RunOnMainThread:ExecuteAll() (at Z:/tmp/tmp.cfOHeQ7pJN/third_party/unity/unity_jar_resolver/source/VersionHandlerImpl/src/RunOnMainThread.cs:406)
Google.RunOnMainThread:Run(Action, Boolean) (at Z:/tmp/tmp.cfOHeQ7pJN/third_party/unity/unity_jar_resolver/source/VersionHandlerImpl/src/RunOnMainThread.cs:363)
GooglePlayServices.<GradleResolution>c__AnonStorey1:<>m__8(Result) (at Z:/tmp/tmp.CbcF1w0aJu/third_party/unity/unity_jar_resolver/source/PlayServicesResolver/src/GradleResolver.cs:468)
GooglePlayServices.ProgressReporter:SignalComplete() (at Z:/tmp/tmp.CbcF1w0aJu/third_party/unity/unity_jar_resolver/source/PlayServicesResolver/src/CommandLineDialog.cs:116)
GooglePlayServices.ProgressReporter:CommandLineToolCompletion(Result) (at Z:/tmp/tmp.CbcF1w0aJu/third_party/unity/unity_jar_resolver/source/PlayServicesResolver/src/CommandLineDialog.cs:107)
GooglePlayServices.<RunAsync>c__AnonStorey1:<>m__0() (at Z:/tmp/tmp.CbcF1w0aJu/third_party/unity/unity_jar_resolver/source/PlayServicesResolver/src/CommandLine.cs:137)
Google.RunOnMainThread:ExecuteNext() (at Z:/tmp/tmp.cfOHeQ7pJN/third_party/unity/unity_jar_resolver/source/VersionHandlerImpl/src/RunOnMainThread.cs:377)
Google.RunOnMainThread:<ExecuteAll>m__1() (at Z:/tmp/tmp.cfOHeQ7pJN/third_party/unity/unity_jar_resolver/source/VersionHandlerImpl/src/RunOnMainThread.cs:408)
Google.RunOnMainThread:RunAction(Action) (at Z:/tmp/tmp.cfOHeQ7pJN/third_party/unity/unity_jar_resolver/source/VersionHandlerImpl/src/RunOnMainThread.cs:234)
Google.RunOnMainThread:ExecuteAll() (at Z:/tmp/tmp.cfOHeQ7pJN/third_party/unity/unity_jar_resolver/source/VersionHandlerImpl/src/RunOnMainThread.cs:406)
UnityEditor.EditorApplication:Internal_CallUpdateFunctions()
```

```
Resolution failed
Failed to fetch the following dependencies:
com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:17.2.0
com.google.firebase:firebase-iid:[20.0.0]
com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-unity:6.6.0
com.google.firebase:firebase-common:19.1.0
com.google.firebase:firebase-app-unity:6.6.0
com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:19.0.0
com.google.firebase:firebase-auth-unity:6.6.0
com.google.firebase:firebase-database:19.1.0
com.google.firebase:firebase-database-unity:6.6.0
com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:20.0.0
com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging-unity:6.6.0
UnityEngine.Debug:LogError(Object)
Google.Logger:Log(String, LogLevel) (at Z:/tmp/tmp.cfOHeQ7pJN/third_party/unity/unity_jar_resolver/source/VersionHandlerImpl/src/Logger.cs:103)
GooglePlayServices.PlayServicesResolver:Log(String, LogLevel) (at Z:/tmp/tmp.CbcF1w0aJu/third_party/unity/unity_jar_resolver/source/PlayServicesResolver/src/PlayServicesResolver.cs:957)
GooglePlayServices.GradleResolver:LogMissingDependenciesError(List`1) (at Z:/tmp/tmp.CbcF1w0aJu/third_party/unity/unity_jar_resolver/source/PlayServicesResolver/src/GradleResolver.cs:91)
GooglePlayServices.<DoResolutionUnsafe>c__AnonStorey6:<>m__1(List`1) (at Z:/tmp/tmp.CbcF1w0aJu/third_party/unity/unity_jar_resolver/source/PlayServicesResolver/src/GradleResolver.cs:760)
GooglePlayServices.<GradleResolution>c__AnonStorey1:<>m__0() (at Z:/tmp/tmp.CbcF1w0aJu/third_party/unity/unity_jar_resolver/source/PlayServicesResolver/src/GradleResolver.cs:295)
GooglePlayServices.<GradleResolution>c__AnonStorey1:<>m__2(Result) (at Z:/tmp/tmp.CbcF1w0aJu/third_party/unity/unity_jar_resolver/source/PlayServicesResolver/src/GradleResolver.cs:372)
GooglePlayServices.<GradleResolution>c__AnonStorey2:<>m__0() (at Z:/tmp/tmp.CbcF1w0aJu/third_party/unity/unity_jar_resolver/source/PlayServicesResolver/src/GradleResolver.cs:468)
Google.RunOnMainThread:ExecuteNext() (at Z:/tmp/tmp.cfOHeQ7pJN/third_party/unity/unity_jar_resolver/source/VersionHandlerImpl/src/RunOnMainThread.cs:377)
Google.RunOnMainThread:<ExecuteAll>m__1() (at Z:/tmp/tmp.cfOHeQ7pJN/third_party/unity/unity_jar_resolver/source/VersionHandlerImpl/src/RunOnMainThread.cs:408)
Google.RunOnMainThread:RunAction(Action) (at Z:/tmp/tmp.cfOHeQ7pJN/third_party/unity/unity_jar_resolver/source/VersionHandlerImpl/src/RunOnMainThread.cs:234)
Google.RunOnMainThread:ExecuteAll() (at Z:/tmp/tmp.cfOHeQ7pJN/third_party/unity/unity_jar_resolver/source/VersionHandlerImpl/src/RunOnMainThread.cs:406)
Google.RunOnMainThread:Run(Action, Boolean) (at Z:/tmp/tmp.cfOHeQ7pJN/third_party/unity/unity_jar_resolver/source/VersionHandlerImpl/src/RunOnMainThread.cs:363)
GooglePlayServices.<GradleResolution>c__AnonStorey1:<>m__8(Result) (at Z:/tmp/tmp.CbcF1w0aJu/third_party/unity/unity_jar_resolver/source/PlayServicesResolver/src/GradleResolver.cs:468)
GooglePlayServices.ProgressReporter:SignalComplete() (at Z:/tmp/tmp.CbcF1w0aJu/third_party/unity/unity_jar_resolver/source/PlayServicesResolver/src/CommandLineDialog.cs:116) GooglePlayServices.ProgressReporter:CommandLineToolCompletion(Result) (at Z:/tmp/tmp.CbcF1w0aJu/third_party/unity/unity_jar_resolver/source/PlayServicesResolver/src/CommandLineDialog.cs:107)
GooglePlayServices.<RunAsync>c__AnonStorey1:<>m__0() (at Z:/tmp/tmp.CbcF1w0aJu/third_party/unity/unity_jar_resolver/source/PlayServicesResolver/src/CommandLine.cs:137)
Google.RunOnMainThread:ExecuteNext() (at Z:/tmp/tmp.cfOHeQ7pJN/third_party/unity/unity_jar_resolver/source/VersionHandlerImpl/src/RunOnMainThread.cs:377)
Google.RunOnMainThread:<ExecuteAll>m__1() (at Z:/tmp/tmp.cfOHeQ7pJN/third_party/unity/unity_jar_resolver/source/VersionHandlerImpl/src/RunOnMainThread.cs:408)
Google.RunOnMainThread:RunAction(Action) (at Z:/tmp/tmp.cfOHeQ7pJN/third_party/unity/unity_jar_resolver/source/VersionHandlerImpl/src/RunOnMainThread.cs:234)
Google.RunOnMainThread:ExecuteAll() (at Z:/tmp/tmp.cfOHeQ7pJN/third_party/unity/unity_jar_resolver/source/VersionHandlerImpl/src/RunOnMainThread.cs:406)
UnityEditor.EditorApplication:Internal_CallUpdateFunctions()
```

---

### Firebase Analytics and Auth

I also use Firebase Analytics with Auth.
I imported Analytics first into my project and then Auth.
At that time, I was warned to delete some Analytics files.
I then allowed those files to be deleted.

I also imported Analytics again and tried to import Auth.
I skipped the warning and left the file.

But the error remains both.

Comment: Is the JDK downloaded by Unity the same as the one in JAVA_HOME ?

Comment: No. I don't know where is the JDK downloaded by Unity.
Is there a way to find it?

Comment: Check this link : [environnement setup](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/android-sdksetup.html), try to use the JDK from your JAVA_HOME maybe this will do the trick.

Comment: OpenJDK downloaded. In other words, should [UnityProjectName\AndroidPlayer\Tools\OpenJDK\Windows] be set to JAVA_HOME? I tried it once but it didn't work. [UnityProjectName\...\Windows] cannot be set to JAVA_HOME and can only be used for Unity?

Comment: For what I have seen, if you change your JDK path in your Unity environment you must restart Unity. Your JAVA_HOME must point to a valid path (check if you have the JDK installed where your JAVA_HOME points). Unity also precognise to use a x64 version of the JDK. There doesn't seems to be any problem in your path, you don't have `\bin` at the end which is a common error. I don't think setting OpenJDK to your JAVA_HOME is a good idea since other application might use it as well. 
**TL;DR :** Check your if your JAVA_HOME points to a good path (x64), restart unity, retry.

Comment: I specified the latest downloaded JDK in JAVA_HOME, but the error was not fixed. and in Unity, [JDK Installed with Unity] is checked. Is this state correct?

Comment: Have you tried to uncheck it and use the one from your JAVA_HOME ?

Comment: Yes. I removed the check and specified JAVA_HOME and tried various things, but it did not cure. But there was something else weird. I imported Firebase Analytics first, but later imported Auth. At this time, I deleted some files to complete the Auth import. Does Firebase Analytics and Auth interfere? Should they not be used together?

Sorry for the late comment.

Comment: To be honest, I don't know very well Firebase Analytics nor Auth. If this files are related to your JDK maybe that could interfere but I can't help you more, I'm at a loss here. Have you tried the answer Pux0r3 provided ?

Answer (score 2):

I actually don't have `JAVA_HOME` setup on my Windows machine but have `javac` in my path. Just removing that variable might be enough to get you unstuck.

I will also throw in that I tend to want to do a full logout when changing environment variables to make sure there's nothing holding on to old stuff.

In your comments, I see that others have suggested checking your architecture (x86 vs x64). I would also suggest making sure the `JAVA_HOME` matches `javac` (what's in your `PATH`). You can easily find this in powershell with `get-command javac`.

Whatever solves your issue, if any of this does, this sounds a lot like a bug. I would recommend [filing an issue against the unity-jar-resolver repository](https://github.com/googlesamples/unity-jar-resolver/issues) or with [Firebase Support directly](https://firebase.google.com/support). Include any steps you've tried, this thread, and a workaround if anything here helps. I found [this semi-related bug](https://github.com/googlesamples/unity-jar-resolver/issues/160), but I'm pretty sure you're running into something different.

Comment: thank you for your answer. I have never used PowerShell. I tried get-command javac but got an error. Is my usage correct?Here is the error:


+ get-command C:\Java\jdk-13.0.1
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (C:\Java\jdk-13.0.1:String) [Get-Command], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetCommandCommand

Comment: Omit the path. `get-command javac` will tell you if javac is in your path and which one takes precedence. Java has a tendency of installing versions side by side, so this can help you make sure you configured the right one. This is what I mean with making sure `JAVA_HOME` matches the one in your `PATH`.