# Android Jar Resolver unable to resolve firebase unity 2019.2

Tags: firebase, unity-game-engine, firebase-authentication, google-play-games, external-dependencies

I'm using External Dependency Manager 1.2.115, Gradle 5.1, I have my JAVA_HOME path set correctly and also just recently updated my Google play games plugin for unity to GooglePlayGamesPlugin-0.10.09.
So I attempt to do: Assets > External Dependeny Manager > Android Resolver > Force Resolve

And I get this..

```
Resolution failed

Failed to fetch the following dependencies:
com.google.firebase:firebase-app-unity:+
com.google.firebase:firebase-auth-unity:+
com.google.firebase:firebase-database-unity:+
```

Here's the full log:

```
Resolution failed

Failed to fetch the following dependencies:
com.google.firebase:firebase-app-unity:+
com.google.firebase:firebase-auth-unity:+
com.google.firebase:firebase-database-unity:+


UnityEngine.Debug:LogError(Object)
Google.Logger:Log(String, LogLevel) (at /Users/chkuang/Workspace/Git/unity-jar-resolver/source/VersionHandlerImpl/src/Logger.cs:136)
GooglePlayServices.PlayServicesResolver:Log(String, LogLevel) (at /Users/chkuang/Workspace/Git/unity-jar-resolver/source/AndroidResolver/src/PlayServicesResolver.cs:990)
GooglePlayServices.GradleResolver:LogMissingDependenciesError(List`1) (at /Users/chkuang/Workspace/Git/unity-jar-resolver/source/AndroidResolver/src/GradleResolver.cs:95)
GooglePlayServices.<DoResolutionUnsafe>c__AnonStorey18:<>m__22(List`1) (at /Users/chkuang/Workspace/Git/unity-jar-resolver/source/AndroidResolver/src/GradleResolver.cs:912)
GooglePlayServices.<GradleResolution>c__AnonStorey11:<>m__17() (at /Users/chkuang/Workspace/Git/unity-jar-resolver/source/AndroidResolver/src/GradleResolver.cs:375)
GooglePlayServices.<GradleResolution>c__AnonStorey11:<>m__27() (at /Users/chkuang/Workspace/Git/unity-jar-resolver/source/AndroidResolver/src/GradleResolver.cs:440)
GooglePlayServices.<ProcessAars>c__AnonStorey1B:<>m__24() (at /Users/chkuang/Workspace/Git/unity-jar-resolver/source/AndroidResolver/src/GradleResolver.cs:1111)
Google.RunOnMainThread:ExecutePollingJobs() (at /Users/chkuang/Workspace/Git/unity-jar-resolver/source/VersionHandlerImpl/src/RunOnMainThread.cs:409)
Google.RunOnMainThread:<ExecuteAllUnnested>m__11() (at /Users/chkuang/Workspace/Git/unity-jar-resolver/source/VersionHandlerImpl/src/RunOnMainThread.cs:541)
Google.RunOnMainThread:RunAction(Action) (at /Users/chkuang/Workspace/Git/unity-jar-resolver/source/VersionHandlerImpl/src/RunOnMainThread.cs:343)
Google.RunOnMainThread:ExecuteAllUnnested(Boolean) (at /Users/chkuang/Workspace/Git/unity-jar-resolver/source/VersionHandlerImpl/src/RunOnMainThread.cs:530)
Google.RunOnMainThread:PollOnUpdateUntilComplete(Func`1, Boolean) (at /Users/chkuang/Workspace/Git/unity-jar-resolver/source/VersionHandlerImpl/src/RunOnMainThread.cs:379)
GooglePlayServices.PlayServicesResolver:LabelAssets(IEnumerable`1, Action`1, Boolean, Action`2, Boolean, Boolean) (at /Users/chkuang/Workspace/Git/unity-jar-resolver/source/AndroidResolver/src/PlayServicesResolver.cs:2176)
GooglePlayServices.GradleResolver:ProcessAar(String) (at /Users/chkuang/Workspace/Git/unity-jar-resolver/source/AndroidResolver/src/GradleResolver.cs:1413)
GooglePlayServices.<ProcessAars>c__AnonStorey1B:<>m__24() (at /Users/chkuang/Workspace/Git/unity-jar-resolver/source/AndroidResolver/src/GradleResolver.cs:1081)
Google.RunOnMainThread:ExecutePollingJobs() (at /Users/chkuang/Workspace/Git/unity-jar-resolver/source/VersionHandlerImpl/src/RunOnMainThread.cs:409)
Google.RunOnMainThread:<ExecuteAllUnnested>m__11() (at /Users/chkuang/Workspace/Git/unity-jar-resolver/source/VersionHandlerImpl/src/RunOnMainThread.cs:541)
Google.RunOnMainThread:RunAction(Action) (at /Users/chkuang/Workspace/Git/unity-jar-resolver/source/VersionHandlerImpl/src/RunOnMainThread.cs:343)
Google.RunOnMainThread:ExecuteAllUnnested(Boolean) (at /Users/chkuang/Workspace/Git/unity-jar-resolver/source/VersionHandlerImpl/src/RunOnMainThread.cs:530)
Google.RunOnMainThread:PollOnUpdateUntilComplete(Func`1, Boolean) (at /Users/chkuang/Workspace/Git/unity-jar-resolver/source/VersionHandlerImpl/src/RunOnMainThread.cs:379)
GooglePlayServices.PlayServicesResolver:LabelAssets(IEnumerable`1, Action`1, Boolean, Action`2, Boolean, Boolean) (at /Users/chkuang/Workspace/Git/unity-jar-resolver/source/AndroidResolver/src/PlayServicesResolver.cs:2176)
GooglePlayServices.GradleResolver:ProcessAar(String) (at /Users/chkuang/Workspace/Git/unity-jar-resolver/source/AndroidResolver/src/GradleResolver.cs:1413)
GooglePlayServices.<ProcessAars>c__AnonStorey1B:<>m__24() (at /Users/chkuang/Workspace/Git/unity-jar-resolver/source/AndroidResolver/src/GradleResolver.cs:1081)
Google.RunOnMainThread:ExecutePollingJobs() (at /Users/chkuang/Workspace/Git/unity-jar-resolver/source/VersionHandlerImpl/src/RunOnMainThread.cs:409)
Google.RunOnMainThread:<ExecuteAllUnnested>m__11() (at /Users/chkuang/Workspace/Git/unity-jar-resolver/source/VersionHandlerImpl/src/RunOnMainThread.cs:541)
Google.RunOnMainThread:RunAction(Action) (at /Users/chkuang/Workspace/Git/unity-jar-resolver/source/VersionHandlerImpl/src/RunOnMainThread.cs:343)
Google.RunOnMainThread:ExecuteAllUnnested(Boolean) (at /Users/chkuang/Workspace/Git/unity-jar-resolver/source/VersionHandlerImpl/src/RunOnMainThread.cs:530)
Google.RunOnMainThread:ExecuteAll() (at /Users/chkuang/Workspace/Git/unity-jar-resolver/source/VersionHandlerImpl/src/RunOnMainThread.cs:512)
UnityEditor.EditorApplication:Internal_CallUpdateFunctions()
```

I have searched and searched everywhere, tried almost everything on any page I landed, including this: https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-unity/issues/359 and this is related to my issue but no real answer there: ["Resolution Failed! You application will not run, see the log for details"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59545895/resolution-failed-you-application-will-not-run-see-the-log-for-details)

Help will be appreciated..

Answer (score 0):

Dependencies for Firebase in Unity on Android are [pulled down via Gradle](https://github.com/googlesamples/unity-jar-resolver#resolution-strategies) just like [an Android project](https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup). This means that you'll want to make sure that you have an internet connection and that your firewall isn't blocking the download of these files.

It may be convenient [add a mainTemplate.gradle](https://github.com/googlesamples/unity-jar-resolver#integrate-into-maintemplategradle) file and push off that download/resolution step until you do an Android build. Otherwise, you should run the jar resolver when you have access to these files and make sure you save `Assets/Plugins/Android/` for use when offline.

If you are connected to the internet and don't think you should be blocked by anything, definitely try using the gradle integration and try exporting your build and opening it with Android Studio. If it has anything to do with `JAVA_HOME`, it may work that way (then [opening an issue](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-unity/issues) or [contacting support](https://firebase.google.com/support/troubleshooter/report) could help work towards a real workaround).

Let me know if that helps!

--Patrick

Comment: Thank you so much. I'll give it a try and let you know